# Is there any reason not to use the police siren during driving segments?

Tags: la-noire

Since the traffic simulation in LA Noire basically ignores you, NPC cars tend to hit you or pull directly in front of you when you would have the right-of-way.  The only reliable way of avoiding this seems to be to use the police siren, which causes NPC cars to pull over.

Is there any disadvantage to using the police siren whenever you're driving?  I know you can have your partner drive, but you need to drive around to find various street crime side missions.

Answer (score 2):

No , from what I can gather from videos and message boards. It doesn't seem like driving with your siren impacts the game in a negative way.

Comment: Driving recklessly seems to affect the game negatively if you hit things.

Comment: @Dpeif The original wording of the question mentioned something like that, but I went back and edited it before I actually posted it and must have accidentally removed that part.  Oops.

Comment: Updated the answer, my bad.